# Calculating indexPath.row times a number

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

I am trying to set an `NSInteger` to `indexPath.row * 2` but I get an error:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversation initializing 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') with an expression of type 'long'

Here's my code

```
NSInteger *titleToDelete = indexPath.row * 2;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `*` before `titleToDelete`

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger titleToDelete = indexPath.row * 2;